# how to write the formula in excel vba with use of special symbols

Tags: excel, vba

```
Twsht.Cells(Trow + 1, 15).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(M" & Trow + 1 & Chr(38) & "-" & Chr(38) & "N" & Trow + 1 & ",'Table Array'!$A$2:$D$26,4,FALSE)," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Getting below error message
"Run-Time error 1004"
Application-defined or object-defined error

if i paste below formula directly in cell it working

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(M604&-N604,'Table Array'!$A$2:$D$26,4,FALSE),"")

Comment: use .FormulaR1C1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
Twsht.Cells(Trow + 1, 15).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(M" & Trow + 1 & "&-N" & Trow + 1 & ",'Table Array'!$A$2:$D$26,4,FALSE),"""")"
```